# looking for excel formula combining columns and rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, worksheet-function

Imagine a spreadsheet with 4 columns: A B C D

If the B column is equal to D column, I want in column A the result of column C
for example: if B2 is equal to D2, A2 value should be C2 value 
if not equal it should show empty or false or something

I have uploaded a [sample spreadsheet](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a6dvkxgk86pfb7e/Book2.xlsx)

What is the formula to use?

Comment: hi there, since you were very helpful last time, i thought i will ask something that may be easy for you:

Comment: hi there, since you were very helpful last time, i thought i will ask something that may be easy for you: please go to https://www.dropbox.com/s/632hb4bjdhg0ozs/Book1.xlsx i am trying to find an email from column A looking at column F and have the result in column B. but the result i would like to see the cell location and not the value in the cell, as shown with F7... hope you guys can help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In cell `A2`, simply put:

```
=IF(B2=D2,C2,FALSE)
```

And fill down for the other rows.

The logic should be simple enough to understand. And you can type in something else instead of `FALSE` if you want.

**EDIT:**

As per amendment of problem:

1. First move the column D before column C (meaning Email will be in Column C and Log will be in column D)
2. In cell A2, put the formula `=VLOOKUP(B2,C:D,2,0)`
3. Fill the formula down.

Comment: i have another question that could help me further, same logic but i want to get a value in A2 by looking at: if B2 finds the same value in column D, let's say D5, i want A2= C5 does this make sense?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but if I did right, you can use `=IF(B2=D2,C2,"value")` where value is anything you want to have. If you want to get the value of a specific cell, put the address in there like this: `=IF(B2=D2,C2,E2)` here, would return the value in cell `E2` if the addresses in columns B and D don't match. Otherwise, could you clarify your question?

Comment: ok let me clarify: the value that need to match with B2 in column D could be in any row like D5 or D12 or same row like D2 but i dont know which row in column D so if B2 finds a match in Column D, i want A2 to equal the C value of the match row, i have updated the doc. you can see the yellow color match and A2 should be equal to C9 in that example.. https://www.dropbox.com/s/a6dvkxgk86pfb7e/Book2.xlsx

Comment: hi there, since you were very helpful last time, i thought i will ask something that may be easy for you: please go to dropbox.com/s/632hb4bjdhg0ozs/Book1.xlsx  i am trying to find an email from column A looking at column F and have the result in column B. but the result i would like to see the cell location and not the value in the cell, as shown with F7... hope you guys can help, thanks in advance

Comment: @designvogue Oh, sure. If you want to get F7, you can use this `="F"&MATCH(A1,F:F,0)`. While `VLOOKUP` returns the content of the cell, `MATCH` returns the position in the column/row.

Comment: excellent THANK YOU Jerry! what about if column A is found in column F, then column B result will be "last name" so column D. example, if A1 is found in F(here for instance F8), then B1 is equal to D8 (which is the last name), does it make sense? any clue? thanks in advance

Comment: @designvogue You can use the same thing with D instead of F, that is `="D"&MATCH(A1,F:F,0)` If you want to get the value of that cell, you can use `=INDIRECT("D"&MATCH(A1,F:F,0))`

Comment: hi again, i have another request (sorry i am so bad at excel); please look the file enclosed. i have 2 sheets: sheet 1 =column A i would like to show a yes or no in that column. if in sheet 2 A1 is found in F of sheet 1. if A2 in sheet 2 is found in Column F of sheet 1, etc... retunr the value in sheet 1 column A.  does that make sense? thanks in advance. https://www.dropbox.com/s/632hb4bjdhg0ozs/Book1.xlsx

Comment: sorry let me try to explain again: i want to find out if the emails in sheet 2 column A are in sheet 1 column F. if so, result could say YES, if not it could say NO. that YES or NO will show in column A in sheet 1.

Comment: i guess it is not possible? if i need to put it all on the same sheet or reorgarnize the data/column so i can get the result i want it is fine! thks

Comment: @designvogue Hi! Sorry, I couldn't get online for the past few days. Yes, it's possible, I uploaded the Workbook [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23298677/Book1.xlsx)

Comment: HI again, is there a simple way to remove space on excel. i have a list of email i copy from a folder & paste them on excel. when i paste them, they show on column A row 1 for email 1, row 2 for email 2, etc... now when pasted, there is space before the first letter for example here, there is a space before the letter E at the word example " example@aol.com". so all the emails pasted are like this and i have 100s. the reason i am asking this is because when i do a search or vlookup it does recognize that email because there is a space. any clue on how to remove that space? thanks a million...

Comment: @designvogue Where is the space? In sheet 1 or sheet 2 data?

Comment: on this file you can see that for each email there is a space before the first letter https://www.dropbox.com/s/zstedy09niypq9b/Book3.xlsx

Comment: @designvogue You might want to use `TRIM()` on that column first and replace it with the trimmed results. It'll make the vlookup much slower otherwise, or do a Replace on space.

Comment: i tried the trim before but does not work and the replace space also tried but how i can find a spcace doing REPLACE ALL?

Comment: @designvogue You can copy the character and paste it in find, replace by nothing. Or you can use `=SUBSTITUTE(CHAR(160), "", A1)` in column B of your sheet, then copy/paste values in column A.

Comment: thanks but it does not seem to work. replacing a space by nothing is like replacing nothing by nothing so not sure it works. the substitute formula bring me a blank cell as result on B1, am i doing something wrong? could u send me the file back please so i can see how you did it? thks

Comment: @designvogue well, the Find/Replace requires you to copy the space in front of the email. I found out it wasn't any ordinary space. I just checked the substitute, oops, I put the arguments at the wrong places ^^; Check out the Book1 in my comment of the 21st October which I updated.

Comment: HI Jerry the formula you gave is great but was wondering if it can be tuned. when i look for a match of url basically bet sheet GH and sheet2 in enclosed doc, if the foward slash "com/" after the .com is missing or if "http://" is missing then it does not consider a match and give a NO value when in fact it is the same url. is there something we can do? please see file and first 2 rows. thanks a million!!! https://www.dropbox.com/s/8lco930264c6y1r/Book4.xlsx

Comment: @designvogue Does the blog url in the first sheet always start with `http://`? If so, you can use [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23298677/Book2.xlsx). Otherwise, it might be more problematic.

Answer (score 0):

This would go in A2.

```
=IF(B2=C2,C2,"")
```